# Laravel 4 left join where something is equal Or return zeros

Tags: laravel, join, laravel-4, eloquent, left-join

i need to join two tables whilst summing and counting the second table.
That i have done, but only when the rows exist in the second table.

If there is nothing there, i'd like the join to return zeros, rather than stopping the whole row from being displayed.

I'm sure i need to left join on both uid = uid AND gid = gid, but am not sure how to??

Here's my working, but filtering too much code:

```
$result = Users_team::where('users_teams.gid', '=', $gid)
                        ->leftjoin('events_users', 'users_teams.uid', '=', 'events_users.uid')
                        ->where('events_users.gid', '=', $gid)
                        ->groupBy('users_teams.uid')
                        ->addSelect( array(
                        '*',
                        DB::raw('count(*) as apps'),
                        DB::raw( 'SUM(goals) AS goals' ),
                        DB::raw( 'SUM(assists) AS assists' ),
                        DB::raw( 'SUM(award) AS awards' ),
                        ));
```

Comment: Rather than just show us your SQL, could you by chance show us an example of the data in these two tables as well as what you would like the results to look like with the same data from the two tables included?  It's very hard to figure out what exactly you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer is not to do a separate 'where' inside the left join, which effectively undoes the 'left' part of it.

Instead the join should be made on two conditions, shown below.

```
$result = Users_team::where('users_teams.gid', '=', $gid)
                        ->leftJoin('events_users', function($join)
                            {
                                $join->on('users_teams.uid', '=', 'events_users.uid')
                                ->on('events_users.gid', '=', 'users_teams.gid');
                            })
                        ->groupBy('users_teams.uid')
                        ->addSelect( array(
                        '*',
                        DB::raw('count(*) as apps'),
                        DB::raw( 'SUM(goals) AS goals' ),
                        DB::raw( 'SUM(assists) AS assists' ),
                        DB::raw( 'SUM(award) AS awards' ),
                        ));
```